# React-Native: Hermes is not enabled

Tags: android, react-native, webstorm, react-native-hermes

I am trying to enable [`Hermes`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/hermes) in a new project but despite I have enabled it in `android/app/build.gradle` it is not enabled. I am not able to see `Engine: Hermes` text in app as described in documentation. I am using `WebStorm 2019.2` project template.

**App.js:**

```
// imports
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content"/>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Header/>
          {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
            <View style={styles.engine}>
              <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          // rest of the default ui omitted
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**babel.cofig.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

**metro.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false
      }
    })
  }
};
```

**package.js:**

```
{
  "name": "hermes",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

You can checkout and test the project from [here](https://github.com/olcayertas/empty-hermes-project).

**UPDATE:**

I have manged to enable both `Hermes` and auto linking after upgrading to `RN v0.62.2`. Here is my current settings and dependencies:

- [Package.json](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1980624)
- Project level [build.gradle](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1980626)
- Module level [build.gradle](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1980628)

Comment: You can remove `def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);`

Comment: And `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Comment: clean is not working

Comment: @hongdeveloper, why we should remove this line `def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);`. But this will not be a need for anabling hermes???

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you started your project, you might need to go to `android/gradle.properties` and change
`expo.jsEngine=jsc`
to
`expo.jsEngine=hermes`

make sure to clean gradle: `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`

That's all you need to enable Hermes. To check if you got it right you can use the HermesInternal global variable once the app mounts

```
const isHermes = () => !!global.HermesInternal;
console.log("isHermesEnabled:", isHermes());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just before run the app clear android build using this command `cd android && ./gradlew clean` and run again.